# How to deploy and run clojurescript application in Heroku

Tags: heroku, clojure, clojurescript

I have a template of a clojurescript application from https://github.com/Day8/re-frame-template. So I want to deploy that template without any modifications to Heroku. So I followed the instructions on the [README](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame-template/blob/master/README.md) 
`lein clean` `lein cljsbuild once min`. Then I follow the instructions on Heroku as well on deploying clojure on https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/clojure-support

But when I check if the application runs all I get is an application error. 
So my questions are:

> 1. How does one build and deploy a clojurescript app to heroku?
> 2. What is the difference in deploying a clojurescript app vs a clojure app
> 3. Do I need a clojure server in order to run clojurescript?
> 4. How does one even run a standalone clojurescript app on the desktop?
> 5. How is the generated `app.js` related to running a clojurescript app?

I have found it pretty easy to deploy and run a clojure app on Heroku as well as a standalone applicaton on my desktop, I was hoping the same would be true for clojurescript.

Edited:
The error is here: https://floating-depths-33030.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Show that application error.

Comment: https://jkutner.github.io/2015/10/14/clojurescript-on-heroku.html

Comment: You'll need to serve it somehow - so for Heroku you'll have more luck if you use Luminus with re-frame.

Comment: It worked with `luminus` `+re-frame`

Comment: @KevinKamau if you expand that slightly and post it as an answer it will help people who land here later searching for how to run clojurescript on heroku

Answer (score 1):

To clear the topic for future people finding heroku + clj/cljs, following is a list of working examples. The clojure support on heroku means you can have Clojure webapp deployed. But cljs (like re-frame) actually is pure javascript, have nothing to do with heroku clojure support.

https://github.com/kawasima/back-channeling

https://github.com/zerg000000/table-tmpl

Answer (score 1):

To deploy a `re-frame` application to `Heroku` one needs a `clojure` server, this is where `ring` comes in. In order to add `ring` one needs to add `+handler` while creating a new `re-frame` project as so:

> `lein new re-frame <project-name> +handler`

This will create a project with a configuration that allows it to be deployable to `Heroku`.

Steps to deploy to `Heroku`:

> 1. `lein clean`
> 2. `lein with-profile prod uberjar`
> 3. `git init`
> 4. `git add .`
> 5. `git commit -m "first commit"`
> 6. `git push heroku master`
> 7. `heroku ps:scale web=1`
> 8. `heroku open`

This is application is now readily accessible.